# How to get blank space size when using PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom of PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am using PictureBox class in Windows Forms. Also I set PictureBox's SizeMode to PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom.

[image]
How to calculate this black width what is added to the picture? Or how to get ratio what is used to scale this picture? Is there some existing property to get real size of image?

Comment: PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

Comment: I need to use zoom mode and i need to know what is the ratio to resize another picture manualy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some existing property to get real size of image?

`PictureBox.Image.Size`

> How to calculate this black width what is added to the picture? Or how to get ratio what is used to scale this picture?

There is no standard way of doing that. But you can look at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs,5c2ab37313f547c2 how `PictureBox` does that internally.

Comment: In reference above is one mistake. You have to round all values multiplied to the ratio.  `(int)Math.Round(someValue* ratio, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);`

Comment: @OlegDobra I don't know what do you mean by that, if you haven't noticed, the reference points to the current implementation of the `PictureBox` by Microsoft, not mine. Don't kill the messenger :-)